# scaffold does not update view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I have a question to the following procedure:

- script/generate scaffold product
  title:string description:text
- db:migrate
- ## then I generate a migration which adds a column description to the

  table products and migrate the db
  again.

My question is: why is the field description not added to the project-views? Is that normal rails scaffold behaviour?
I think I saw in a video tutorial that the scaffold updates as well the views, which would be very convenient.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behaviour for scaffolding, however there are alternatives.

If you were to look at [Ryan Bates nifty_scaffold](http://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators) generator then this would allow you to re-run the scaffold generation. **Assuming that you hadn't changed the generated code**.

These generators can regenerate the views/spec/tests based upon the current state of the database model.

Be aware that if you have already customised the views yourself then they could be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! I thought I have seen that the views were updated automatically in a tutorial, but I might be wrong.
Thanks Steven for the nifty_scaffold tip, I think I'm gonna give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

This is normal since scaffold does not "monitor" changes to the table or to any other scaffold-related resource (controller, model, views, tests, etc.).

> then I generate a migration which
>   adds a column description to the table
>   products

You have description column already when generating the scaffold. Why do you need another migration for this?